# Create Task Scheduler with monthly execution using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a task scheduler like below

[image]

So far I came up with below code.

```
#Variables
$TaskName = "TestingTask"
$username ="user"
$password ='password'
$description = "This is a testing task"
 
#Create Scheduled Task
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "E:\script.ps1"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 10AM -Weekly -WeeksInterval 2 -DaysOfWeek Friday
$taskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'user' -RunLevel Highest
$ScheduledTask = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Description $description -Principal $taskPrincipal
 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -InputObject $ScheduledTask -User $username -Password $password
```

Please let me know how can we schedule monthly like this.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've already written?

Comment: the code I have written is fine. but I am not getting any options to schedule monthly as per the screen shot. i tried weekly it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can't do monthly schedules in PowerShell with this cmdlet. The `schtasks.exe` utility can though...

```
schtasks.exe /Create /?
```

(abridged)

```
/MO   modifier     Refines the schedule type to allow finer control over schedule recurrence. Valid values are listed in the "Modifiers" section below.

/SC   schedule     Specifies the schedule frequency.
                   Valid schedule types: MINUTE, HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, ONCE, ONSTART, ONLOGON, ONIDLE, ONEVENT.

Modifiers: Valid values for the /MO switch per schedule type:
MINUTE:  1 - 1439 minutes.
HOURLY:  1 - 23 hours.
DAILY:   1 - 365 days.
WEEKLY:  weeks 1 - 52.
ONCE:    No modifiers.
ONSTART: No modifiers.
ONLOGON: No modifiers.
ONIDLE:  No modifiers.
MONTHLY: 1 - 12, or FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH, LAST, LASTDAY.
ONEVENT:  XPath event query string.

Examples:
    ==> Creates a scheduled task "gametime" to run freecell on the
    first Sunday of every month.

    SCHTASKS /Create /SC MONTHLY /MO first /D SUN /TN gametime
             /TR c:\windows\system32\freecell
```

Pro Tip: dynamically build your command as a string in PowerShell, then use `Invoke-Expression` to execute it.

Answer (score -1):

From the help for the cmdlet `Get-Help New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -full`

```
Example 4: Register a scheduled task that starts every-other week

PS C:\>$Sta = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Cmd"

The second command creates a scheduled task trigger that starts every other Sunday at 3:00 A.M and assigns the ScheduledTaskTrigger object to the $Stt variable.
PS C:\>$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 2 -DaysOfWeek Sunday -At 3am

The third command registers the scheduled task Task01 to run the task action named Cmd every other Sunday at 3:00 A.M.
PS C:\>Register-ScheduledTask Task01 -Action $Sta -Settings $Stt

This example registers a scheduled task that starts every other week.

The first command creates a scheduled task action named Cmd and assigns the ScheduledTaskAction object to the $Sta variable.
```

I would assume that if you set `-Weekly -WeeksInterval 4` should set the task to run once every 4 weeks, and should essentially make it a month. But you are right, there is no real option to identify a "month", you should try this out and see how it looks like the GUI.

Another thing to try is, to make a montly based task in the GUI and use `Get-ScheduledTask` to see how the interval is configured.